# ADBannerView not re-appearing after segueing out of the view

Tags: swift, iad

**Preamble:** I have a view controller with a ADBannerView to do iAds. It is the only view controller with the iAd, and when I segue to another view controller, I want the iAd to disappear; It will only be active on that one view controller.

As per Apple's iAd guidelines: "If the user navigates from a screen of content with a banner view to a screen that does not have a banner view, remove the banner view from the view hierarchy, set its delegate to nil, and release it before transitioning to the new screen of content."

What I did:

```
iAdBanner.removeFromSuperview() //remove from view hierarchy(correct?)


iAdBanner.delegate = nil // set delegate to nil
```

Apple also mentioned to "release [the ADBannerView] before transitioning...". How do I "release" it? Do I even need to now that we're using ARC for memory management?

**Dilemma:** After segueing out of the screen and segueing back into the screen, iAd no longer refreshes it's advertisements. It doesn't load any ads. What happened? Below is my code for implementing the iAd.

[image: stuff]

[image: prepareForSegue]

[image: adViewBannerDelegate]

Comment: After more research, I tweaked some things and now I have a different problem. I'm editing the question now.